# NetworkError: 404 Not Found IIS Windows 2008 R2

Tags: jquery, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have dedicated windows 2008 R2 server where I have IIS website in html website. Every thing is working fine but on some of the pages **when I go to firebug I can see that some css and jQuery files are showing NetworkError: 404 not found**

But when I go to the directory on the server physically files are there then why it is showing not found !!!

can somebody tell me what can be the issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In IIS there was IIS URL Scan, So I disable it by below steps

1. Go to the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet
   Information Services
2. Click WebSites folder, right click to get Properties
3. Click ISAPI Filters tab, find URLScan in the list, click Remove
   button, then OK to save
4. From Command Prompt (Start -> Run -> Cmd), type “iisreset”, to
   restart IIS